# jquery ajax call causes browser error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

HTML code:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="color: #555" style="display:block; ">
<input type="text" id="id_site" placeholder="nom-du-site" style="width: 245px;  font-size: 16px;">
<div style="float: right; color: black; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -6px">.domain.com</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="spacing">
<a href="" id="envoyer" class="bouton">Envoyer</a>
```

Here is the javascript code with Query Ajax call:

```
    $("#envoyer").click(function (e) {

        // checks user input:
        nom = document.getElementById('id_nom');
        email = document.getElementById('id_email');
        site = document.getElementById('id_site');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/website/script.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                nom: nom,
                email: email,
                site: site
            },
            success: function (json) {
                DataSeries = json;
            },
            error: branchAjaxFailed
        });

});
```

Here is script.php (at the moment):

```
<?
if (isset($_GET["nom"])) $nom = $_GET["nom"];
if (isset($_GET["email"])) $email = $_GET["email"];
if (isset($_GET["site"])) $site = $_GET["site"];
?>
```

- Chrome freezes indefinitely. If I add a debug break after this Ajax call, Chrome never gets there in the 'inspect element' tool.
- IE gives me a "Stack overflow at line 2" error.

Can anyone see what the problem is ?

Comment: In firebug, there is a net tab. expand your XHR request and see what is in the response.

Comment: Does the PHP script work properly without using an Ajax call?

Comment: @nmford Yes the PHP script works fine when called directly in the browser.

Comment: You have not posted enough code.

Comment: Second thing you can do is remove `dataType` parameter and check. I think your php is not sending response in proper format.

Comment: @MotaBOS I checked the Firebug Net tab but the Ajax call does not show. Same in Chrome.

Comment: Then I guess the ajax request is not being sent. When are you sending this request ?

Comment: @Pointy I added more code to show html, javascript, and the php file called by ajax

Comment: @MetaBOS I added more code showing when the Ajax is called.

Comment: Does the browser hang when you click on that button?  (By the way, you need to be sending the "value" attribute of "nom", "email", and "site", though that won't cause the problem.)

Comment: @Pointy Yes the browser hangs when I click on the button.

Comment: Well there's nothing about that code you've posted that would cause the browser to hang. Perhaps you can set breakpoints at the start of that function and figure out what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things, I found the "guilty" part: the following html code was causing problem:

```
<a href="" id="envoyer" class="bouton">Envoyer</a>
```

Removing the href fixes the problem:

```
<a id="envoyer" class="bouton">Envoyer</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the JQuery getJSON when dealing with JSONP, is your server set up to handle JSONP? For example if I was calling the Flickr API I might have something like below (un tested):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?",
{
  tags : 'Apple',
  tagmode : "any",
  method : "flickr.photos.search",
},
function(data) {
  $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
    var src = "http://farm"+ item.farm +".static.flickr.com/"+ item.server +"/"+ item.id +"_"+ item.secret +"_m.jpg";
    var image = $('<img class="flickr" alt="' + item.title + '" />');
    image.load(function() {
      $(this).animate({ 'opacity':1 }, { duration:300, queue:false });
    });
    $('#images').append($('<a href="'+srcLarge+'" rel="prettyPhoto[location]" />').append(image));
    image.attr('src',src);
  });
 });
```